# The method "device.press" or "device.touch" of MonkeyRunner doesn't take effect

Tags: android, testing, monkeyrunner, monkey

I want to use monkeyrunner to test my MainActivity,and I have edit a python file like below:

```
    from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice
    device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(10)
    device.press('KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN')
    device.press('KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER')
    device.touch(10,100, 'DOWN_AND_UP')
    device.touch(200,200, 'DOWN_AND_UP')
    result = device.takeSnapshot()
    result.writeToFile('shot2.png','png')
```

And then I open up my app and use the command of "monkeyrunner monkeyrunnerprogram2.py",but the monkey runner can do nothing except takesnapshot().It doesnot do anything above. 
So is there anyway to solve the problem?

Comment: It would help if you could give more details. What are you trying to do with your script? A screen capture would be of help too.

Comment: @GabrielPorumb Thank you for commenting. I have a listview in my activity and I want to test if the applciation will be crashed when I touch or scroll the listview.But the monkeyrun doesn't take effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to replace 'DOWN_AND_UP' with MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP. And you could also add some MonkeyRunner.sleep(time_in_seconds) to pause the script between the interactions.

To test if the device object was properly created you could use device.wake() which lights up the device's display. If this works, the touch and press methods should work also.

Comment: That's cool.The main reason why it didn't take effect before is I didn't call "MonkeyRunner.sleep".Now it runs fun.Thank you very much!